# Setting up MouseWheelZoom on the map in OpenLayers3

Tags: openlayers, maps, angular

Well, I`m working on my own pet-project and using for this OL3. I need much help with creating a zoom for my map. The documentation for OL says that they do not have a built-in zoom by default, and an example of using a polyphile is also given. Unfortunately, the code was not working, and I could not solve the error.

Is there any other way to arrange zoom for the map?

Comment: Mouse wheel zoom is a built in interaction 
https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.interaction.html#.defaults https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/simple.html

Comment: @Mike could you put your comment as an answer ? It sound correct to me.